# Using .loc to categorize continuous data for range of values

Tags: pandas

```
0,  10.65
1,  15.27
2,  15.96
3,  13.49
4,  12.69
5,   7.90
6,  15.96
7,  18.64
8,  21.28
9,  12.69
10, 14.65
11, 12.69
12, 13.49
13,  9.91
14, 10.65
15, 16.29
```

the code I write is

```
data2.loc[data2['int_rate'] <= 8.00, 'int_rate'] = "low"
data2.loc[8.00 < data2['int_rate'] <= 30.00, 'int_rate'] = "medium"
data2.loc[15.00 < data2['int_rate'] < 30.00, 'int_rate'] = "high"
```

In result I get all the value lower than 8.0 as low but no changes to other value.

Comment: Why in the first line you reference `data2`, while in the other ones you reference `data`? Is this a typo?

Comment: that was typo but it doesn't work, I solved it another way

Comment: @AyushJaiswal You can post your method as answer to help other people encountering this problem.

Comment: As said, kindly consider sharing your solution here by posting an answer.

Comment: will do it asap please help me with problem that how can I plot a count plot by considering a single unique value of column as hue                                  
sns.countplot(y = data2['purpose'], hue=data2['loan_status'], data=data2) here I want select a single value of column loan_status

Answer (score 0):

The answer my problem will be:

```
data2['int_rate'] =  (pd.cut(data2.int_rate, bins=[0, 8.00, 15.00, 30.00], labels=['low', 'medium', 'high']))
```

above code will implent the low to values lower than 8.00 and high to its respectively.

Comment: Hello Ayush Jaiswal, please do not post part of you question as an answer. You can edit your question.

Comment: Hello Ric Villalba, I don't think any need to edit my question. I just found solution to my problem and shared it to the community.